# SQL to find the date when the price last changed

Tags: sql

Input:

```
Date    Price

12/27    5
12/21    5
12/20    4
12/19    4
12/15    5
```

Required Output: 
The earliest date when the price was set in comparison to the current price. 
For e.g., price has been 5 since **12/21**.

The answer cannot be 12/15 as we are interested in finding the earliest date where the price was the same as the current price without changing in value(on 12/20, the price has been changed to 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be about right. You didn't provide table structures or names, so...

```
DECLARE @CurrentPrice MONEY

SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentPrice=Price FROM Table ORDER BY Date DESC

SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Table WHERE Price=@CurrentPrice AND Date>(
    SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table WHERE Price<>@CurrentPrice
)
```

In one query:

```
SELECT MIN(Date) 
FROM Table 
WHERE Date >
      ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
        FROM Table 
        WHERE Price <> 
              ( SELECT TOP 1 Price 
                FROM Table 
                ORDER BY Date DESC
              )
      )
```

Comment: I assume that you assume that it is for SQL-Server from the OP's name. Right?

Comment: The `Price=@CurrentPrice` can be removed, too.

Comment: @ypercube - I assumed SQL Server based on OP's previous questions. Your query almost certainly performs better, but I generally avoid nested queries for legibility, especially in examples. The only reason I didn't turn the MAX(Date) nest into a separate query was because I didn't know the datatype of Date.

Answer (score 0):

This question kind of makes no sense so im not 100% sure what you are after.

create four columns, old_price, new_price, old_date, new_date.

! if old_price === new_price, simply print the old_date.

Answer (score 0):

What database server are you using? If it was Oracle, I would use their windowing function. Anyway, here is a quick version that works in mysql:

Here is the sample data:

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
| date       | product_id | price_on_date |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 2011-01-01 |          1 |             5 |
| 2011-01-03 |          1 |             4 |
| 2011-01-05 |          1 |             6 |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Here is the query (it only works if you have 1 product - will have to add a "and product_id = ..." condition on the where clause if otherwise).

```
SELECT p.date as last_price_change_date
FROM test.prices p
left join test.prices p2 on p.product_id = p2.product_id and p.date < p2.date
where p.price_on_date - p2.price_on_date <> 0
order by p.date desc
limit 1
```

In this case, it will return "2011-01-03".

Not a perfect solution, but I believe it works. Have not tested on a larger dataset, though.

Make sure to create indexes on date and product_id, as it will otherwise bring your database server to its knees and beg for mercy.

Bernardo.